# Instantiate reduce tasks with map tasks in parallel

Tags: hadoop

For internal reason, I'd like Hadoop to instantiate Reduce tasks together with Map tasks in parallel. I mean, Hadoop should not wait for some progress from Map tasks to start Reduce tasks.

I've tried `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0` with no luck.

Hadoop 2.7.1

LocalJobRunner (not a pseudo-distibuted mode)

Comment: Where are you setting this value: mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps?

Comment: I tried to set it through java Configuration `conf.setFloat("mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps", 0)`  and via mapred-site.xml

Comment: and through HADOOP_OPTS: -Dmapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0.00

Comment: Can you tell me, when do the reducers start? After what percent of mappers, do the reducers start?

Comment: @ManjunathBallur because of streaming transport (custom implementation), our mappers should wait for all reducers to be initialized to start doing mapping. But reducers don't being initialized at all. Thus, mappers can't have any progress.